# Convert a 2D grouped array into a consolidated object array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array coming in that looks something like this:

```
[0: {CODE: '9945', Qty: 0, UserInfo: {…}},1: {CODE: '9944', Qty: 4, UserInfo: {…}},2: {CODE: '9945', Qty: 0, UserInfo: {…}},3: {CODE: '9943', Qty: 1, UserInfo: {…}}]
```

The problem with it is that it is based on the CODE, and so for each user I might have a few items that correspond to that user in the list. So I grouped it by UserID, and got something like this:

```
[
2f6de0ce-e701-47e9-9699-77e57090b3a7: Array(2)
0: {CODE: '9945', Qty: 0, UserInfo: {…}}
1: {CODE: '9944', Qty: 1, UserInfo: {…}}
7e01550f-efaa-41cc-8d2f-a5d681d3014a: [{…}]
932f16b1-734d-4134-9f2c-4f5cabb9df84: (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
6693c586-2127-4c3e-8ac7-94b5ff81d317: (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
]
```

Now I would like to use some kind of .map on this to get an array of objects that look like this:

```
return allReports.map((r) => {
            
            return {
                UserName: `${r.UserInfo.LastName}, ${r.UserInfo.FirstName}`,
                DOB: r.UserInfo.DOB,
                CODE_9945: r.CODE === "9945" ? r.Qty : 0,
                CODE_9944: r.CODE === "9944" ? r.Qty : 0,
                CODE_9943: r.CODE === "9943" ? r.Qty : 0
            };
```

I might not tackled it correctly by grouping it .. Is there a better way of getting a consolidated 1D array that will give me the user and the 3 codes that correspond if found. If not, then just put a 0.

Comment: Just wondering about the `0: {CODE: '9945', Qty: 0, UserInfo: {…}}
1: {CODE: '9944', Qty: 1, UserInfo: {…}}` - isn't the UserInfo the same for e.g. UserID 2f6de0ce-e701-47e9-9699-77e57090b3a7 ?

Comment: Yea its a copy/paste problem -- dup. Thanks .. I'll fix

Comment: I see you edited your post but it ain't what I meant. UserID 2f6de0ce-e701-47e9-9699-77e57090b3a7 is an array of two objects, where each object has it's own UserInfo property. Is this two times the same?

Comment: You're looking at the grouped array by userid. In the original array, this user has 2 entries, one for each code. Yea, the userinfo in each will be the same because it corresponds to the same user.

Comment: I think you could use reduce to create your array: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce